# Setting an initial scroll position of a React Native ListView

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to set the initial scroll position of a ListView in react native.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let i = this.props.images.indexOf(this.props.current);
  if(i != -1) {
    this.refs.listView.scrollTo({ x:i*this.props.width, y:0, animated:false });
  }
}
```

where the `images` prop is the datasource for the ListView, the `current` prop is where I want to be initially scrolled to, and the `width` prop is the width of the component. (The component scrolls horizontally).

This works, but there's a delay between the initial render and the call to `componentDidMount`, giving me a flash of the end of end of the list before the list is scrolled.

Is there a way of setting an initial scroll position of the list? Or better way of doing this to get rid of that flash?

Comment: On iOS you can use the `contentOffset` property: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentoffset - not sure what the best x-platform way is.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that. I guess I forgot to look in the underlying scrollview's properties. Put it down as an answer and I'll give it a check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On iOS you can use the [`ScrollView#contentOffset`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentoffset) to set the initial scroll position of a ListView, which inherits the properties of `ScrollView`.

If you are looking for an Android solution, the `ListView.scrollTo` method you are calling seems like the best bet for the general case.

That said, if I interpret your code sample correctly, you are using the ListView for a paginated, horizontal list, perhaps with the help of the `pagingEnabled` property? If this is the case, on Android you might look at using [`ViewPagerAndroid`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewpagerandroid.html) instead, and setting the `initialPage` property.